# Using 'in' in Join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have two selects a & b and i join them like:

```
select * from 
(
   select n.id_b || ',' || s.id_b ids, n.name, s.surname 
   from names n, 
        surnames s where n.id_a = s.id_a
) a 
left join
(
    select sn.id, sn.second_name
) b on b.id in (a.ids)
```

in this case join doesn't work :(
The problem is in **b.id in (a.ids)**. But why if it looks like 12 in (12,24) and no result :(

Comment: what are you trying to achieve through this query?

Comment: the thing i want is:
in select A i have two id's concatenated
in select B i have id as one which used in A select 
and i want to join by these id's
How can i do this?

Comment: Are you getting an error or just no returns?

Comment: it doesn't join, just left table shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because  `(12,24)` is a single discrete string not a comma-separated set of numbers.  Clearly, `12 != '(12,24)'`,  hence no results are returned.

**edit**

I missed the outer join in your posted query.  So you ought to get *something* back, even though there is no join between the two tables.  Here is some test data:

```
SQL> select * from names
  2  /

      ID_A       ID_B NAME
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         12 SAM

SQL> select * from surnames
  2  /

      ID_A       ID_B SURNAME
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         24 I-AM

SQL> select * from whatever
  2  /

        ID SECOND_NAM
---------- ----------
        24 I AM SAM

SQL>
```

My query is similar to yours except I cast `b.id` as a string because `a.ids` is a string.  If I don't do this, the query fails with `ORA-1722: invalid number`.

```
SQL> select * from
  2      (
  3           select n.id_b || ',' || s.id_b ids, n.name, s.surname
  4           from names n,
  5                surnames s
  6           where n.id_a = s.id_a
  7      ) a
  8  left join
  9      (
 10          select sn.id, sn.second_name
 11          from whatever sn
 12      ) b on to_char(b.id) in (a.ids)
 13  /

IDS        NAME       SURNAME            ID SECOND_NAM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
12,24      SAM        I-AM

SQL>
```

As you can see, it returns values from the left-hand query and nothing from the right, for the reason which I gave above.

If you want to get something from both queries on the basis on partial matching of the IDs you need to do this:

```
SQL> select a.ids
  2         , a.name
  3         , a.surname
  4         , b.id
  5         , b.second_name
  6  from
  7      (
  8           select n.id_b || ',' || s.id_b ids
  9                  , n.name
 10                  , s.surname
 11                  , n.id_b as n_id_b
 12                  , s.id_b as s_id_b
 13           from names n,
 14                surnames s
 15           where n.id_a = s.id_a
 16      ) a
 17  left join
 18      (
 19          select sn.id, sn.second_name
 20          from whatever sn
 21      ) b on (b.id = a.n_id_b or b.id = a.s_id_b )
 22  /

IDS        NAME       SURNAME            ID SECOND_NAM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
12,24      SAM        I-AM               24 I AM SAM

SQL>
```

If you take this latter approach you may want to consider turning the outer join into an inner.  Depnds on you precise business rule.

Comment: I would guess he's using `in` because he doesn't know ahead of time how many itms will be in `a.ids`.